# Android 3.x EditText cursor color

Tags: android, colors, cursor, android-edittext

I have a problem with the EditText in Android 3.0:
When i change the textColor property to black (or other color) the text cursor is remains white. I tried to change layer type, color apperance, sdk 11, sdk 12, but no success.
In my project's design all EditText is white, so the cursor is invisible. Anyone can help to me to solve this problem?
Thank You!

Apoth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can create your own EditText style, you can use a drawable for the cursor using [this attribute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#textCursorDrawable)

```
   android:textCursorDrawable
```

Comment: Thank you! ! think this is the "Plan B", the setCursorDrawable is only available from api level 12, so if there other solution, i want to keep the project's api level in 11

Answer (score 6):

You also can set `android:textCursorDrawable` to `@null` value to use `android:textColor` of your EditText as your cursor color.

Comment: Note this keeps the 'shadow' drawable of the edittext it seems. For example, I turned my cursor white, and I had this weird black glow around the cursor which made it look terrible.

Answer (score 0):

If want use Different cursor colour and different text colour for Edit box in 3.0 OS. Use  android:textCursorDrawable as image  like: android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/cursor"
and android:textColor="@color/black".